# Do we have to explitly use Left Join query while using JPA in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I am working in SpringBoot and I am using JPA repositories for DB access. I have two entities say

```
Class A{
 @Id
 private String primarykeyColumnA;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="campaign",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })

private Set<B> b;
 ....
}

Class B{
 @Id
 private Long primaryKeyColB;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.REMOVE })
@JoinColumn(name = "primarykeyColumnA") 
private A a;
}
```

So I have to join these two tables and it is one to many(for one A, there will be many B) relationship. It works fine. But I want to make sure I use Left join. Is it normally Left join or should I specifically use a query?

Some help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the JPA provider you use. In the case of Hibernate, with the *fetch=EAGER* attribute, Hibernate will not perform what you are expecting when you load some A entities.

Instead the following steps will be performed:

- Perform a SQL query to load the A entities, without loading the B entities.
- For each A entity, perform a SQL query to load its related B entities.

If the B entities are not in the cache, you will have the 1+n queries problem.

If you want to load the A entities with the related B entities with a single SQL query, you have to use a query using the *join fetch* clause (left, inner, ... depending on your case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using Hibernate. I do not understand the 1+n queries problem you mentioned. My concern was, say if there is no B associated with a particular A. In case of inner join, I will not get any result since there will be no B value for corresponding A right?

Comment: The 1+n problem means that, when you perform a JPA query on the A entity, Hibernate will create 1 SQL query to load the A entities, and then n SQL queries to load the B entities for each A entity previously loaded. In that case you won't have problems if there are not any B entities related to A.